# SwiftUI - No AutoFill Credentials with HTTP Basic Authentication

Tags: swift, uikit, swiftui, sfsafariviewcontroller

I am struggeling to implement an AutoFill option if I want to access a webpage that uses http basic authentication.

[image: In my App]

On a "normal" login page in my App accessing the AutoFill works fine (Capability "AutoFill Credential Provider" is set correctly).

I tried a UIViewControllerRepresentable first and after that I used a seperate HostingController but both have the same behaviour:

UIViewControllerRepresentable:

```
import SwiftUI
import SafariServices

struct SafariView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    let url: URL
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<SafariView>) -> SFSafariViewController {
        return SFSafariViewController(url: url)
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: SFSafariViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<SafariView>) {
    }
    
}
```

Seperate HostingController:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import SafariServices

class HSHosting {
    static var controller:UIViewController?
    static var nextModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationStyle?

    static func openSafari(url:URL,tint:UIColor? = nil) {
        guard let controller = controller else {
            preconditionFailure("No controller present. Did you remember to use HSHostingController instead of UIHostingController in your SceneDelegate?")
        }

        let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url)

        vc.preferredBarTintColor = tint

        controller.present(vc, animated: true)
    }
}

class HSHostingController<Content> : UIHostingController<Content> where Content : View {

    override init(rootView: Content) {
        super.init(rootView: rootView)

        HSHosting.controller = self
    }

    @objc required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {

        if let nextStyle = HSHosting.nextModalPresentationStyle {
            viewControllerToPresent.modalPresentationStyle = nextStyle
            HSHosting.nextModalPresentationStyle = nil
        }

        super.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag, completion: completion)
    }

}
```

When I open the same URL directly in Safari I get the AutoFill option as expected:

[image: Works in Safari]